# MongoDB $lookup and $group returns empty Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use the following aggregation:

```
[
    {$unwind: '$names'},
    {$sort: {'names.changed_at': -1}},
    {$group: {_id: '$_id', names: {$push: {value: '$names.value', changed_at: '$names.changed_at'}}}},
    {$limit: 3},
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'users',
            localField: 'id',
            foreignField: 'id',
            as: 'user',
        },
    },
    {$unwind: '$user'},
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            old_name: {$first: '$names'},
            user: {avatar_url: 1, current_tag: 1},
        },
    }
]
```

With $lookup and $group it returns [].
When I remove either $lookup or $group it works and gives the expected result.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use the `id` field for the `$lookup` but after this `$group` stage:

```
{ $group: { _id: '$_id', names: { $push: { value: '$names.value', changed_at: '$names.changed_at' } } } },
```

The document structure is:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId,
  names: { value: string, changed_at: Date }[]
}
```

As you can see, there is no `id` field.

If this is a typo just change `id` to `_id`. if this is not a typo then you need to "save" the `id` field in the `$group` stage, like so:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: '$_id',
        names: {$push: {value: '$names.value', changed_at: '$names.changed_at'}},
        id: {$first: "$id"}
    }
}
```

Comment: It was not a typo ^^ I appreciate your help!